# Function template detection through SFINAE

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming, sfinae

I want to write a function that dispatches a lambda either to an external library function template (if this function template exists within the library) or to execute the lambda directly.
We can do this using SFINAE shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

#ifdef _HAS_THE_FUNC
//This part comes from an external library that either provides the function (in an older version) or not (in a newer version).
namespace ext { namespace lib {
  template<int N = 1, typename F>
  void lib_fun(F f) {
    std::cout << "LibFun<" << N << ">" << std::endl;
    f();
  }
} }
#endif
// "Inject" a little helper into the library's namespace to detect the presence of the function
namespace ext { namespace lib {
  // Helper type to detect the presence of lib_fun
  template <typename F>
  struct has_lib_fun {
    template <typename Fun>
    static auto test(int) -> decltype(lib_fun<int{}>(std::declval<Fun>()), std::true_type{});

    template <typename>
    static auto test(...) -> std::false_type;

    using type = decltype(test<F>(0));
    static constexpr bool value = type::value;
  };
  // Use SFINAE to conditionally select the return type of loop_fuse
  template <int N = 1, typename F>
  auto safe_lib_fun(F f, int) -> std::enable_if_t<has_lib_fun<F>::value> {
    lib_fun<N>(f);
  }
  template <int N = 1, typename F>
  auto safe_lib_fun(F f, double) {
    std::cout << "Workaround" << std::endl;
    return f();
  }
} }

int main() {
  ext::lib::safe_lib_fun([]() { std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl; }, 0);
  ext::lib::safe_lib_fun<2>([]() { std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl; }, 0);
  return 0;
}
```

[If I build and run the code](https://godbolt.org/z/7Gje87e9E), I get the expected output:
`clang++ -std=c++17 main.cpp -o woFun && clang++ -std=c++17 main.cpp -D_HAS_THE_FUNC -o wFun`

```
#./woFun
Workaround
Hello World
#./wFun
LibFun<1>
Hello World
```

However, when I try to [build the code with GCC using **c++17**](https://godbolt.org/z/Eob4o4xre) (everything is fine when using c++20), I get the following errors (if the function template is not present):

```
<source>:20:39: error: 'lib_fun' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'has_lib_fun'?
   20 |     static auto test(int) -> decltype(lib_fun<int{}>(std::declval<F>()), std::true_type{});
      |                                       ^~~~~~~
      |                                       has_lib_fun
<source>:20:39: error: 'lib_fun' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'has_lib_fun'?
   20 |     static auto test(int) -> decltype(lib_fun<int{}>(std::declval<F>()), std::true_type{});
      |                                       ^~~~~~~
      |                                       has_lib_fun
<source>: In function 'std::enable_if_t<ext::lib::has_lib_fun<_F>::value> ext::lib::safe_lib_fun(_F, int)':
<source>:31:5: error: 'lib_fun' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'has_lib_fun'?
   31 |     lib_fun<_N>(f);
      |     ^~~~~~~
```

How can I check for the existence of the function template prior with C++11/17?

Comment: what did you try? Whats the problem with just adding it?

Comment: No sure I really get it, but can't you just check if your function accepts that argument like this `lib_fun<int{}>(std::declval<F>())` and then use it as usual?

Comment: *"How can I add the non-type template parameter _N to safe_lib_fun?"* https://godbolt.org/z/aq5bq1Y5n isn't it trivial to solve? I don't really get the issue with adding an NTTP to it ...

Comment: Also remember that names like `_F` are reserved names (all names starting with underscore followed by upper case letter), so that makes for a bad naming scheme for template parameters.

Comment: The problem is that the proposed solutions work with clang, but not with g++ (https://godbolt.org/z/Eob4o4xre)

Comment: @JanSchultke True. I changed the original code accordingly

Comment: if you need help to fix the non working code with gcc, you should mention that in the question, include the code and the error message. Its not obvious what the issue is with adding the non type parameter from your question

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I updated the question accordingly. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: It doesn't work for Clang either. In the CE link you've sent, the only reason why Clang compiles is that you've provided `-D_HAS_THE_FUNC`. If `lib_fun` is not declared at the point where your helper struct is defined, your program is ill-formed.

Comment: @JanSchultke The provided link (https://godbolt.org/z/7Gje87e9E) has two compilers, one with and one without the define. Both work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is impossible without some changes to `lib_fun`.

> ```cpp
> template<int N = 1, typename F>
> void lib_fun(F f) {
>   std::cout << "LibFun<" << N << ">" << std::endl;
>   f();
> }
> ```

The problem here is that `N` is not deducible from the function parameters, so you would have to call it like `lib_fun<N>(f)` in your expression tester (unless you never provided `N`, but that defeats the purpose of this template parameter).
This runs into the problem:

> Knowing which names are type names allows the syntax of every template to be checked. **The program is ill-formed**, no diagnostic required, if:
>
> - [...]
> - a **hypothetical instantiation** of a template **immediately following its definition** would be ill-formed due to a construct that does not depend on a template parameter, or

- [[temp.res] p8.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.res#8.3)

The syntax `lib_fun<N>(f)` in your expression tester `has_lib_fun` is always ill-formed if `lib_fun` isn't defined at that point.
The reason why `lib_fun(f)` would work is that hypothetically, `lib_fun` could be found through argument dependent lookup (ADL) for some arguments `f`, so the compiler cannot reject it with an error despite `lib_fun` not being defined.

#### Solution

```cpp
#ifdef _HAS_THE_FUNC
namespace ext { namespace lib {
  template<int _N = 1, typename _F>
  void lib_fun(_F f) {
    std::cout << "LibFun<" << _N << ">" << std::endl;
    f();
  }
} }
#else
namespace ext { namespace lib {
  template<int _N = 1, typename _F>
  void lib_fun(_F f) = delete;
} }
#endif
```

*See [live solution at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/63bGzqfnY)*.

If `lib_fun` is deleted, not undefined when `_HAS_THE_FUNC` is undefined, then the expression `lib_fun<N>(f)` could still be valid, hypothetically.

It wouldn't be valid once instantiated because `lib_fun` is defined as deleted, but it hypothetically could be valid for some instantiations of `has_lib_fun` and specializations of `lib_fun`, so the compiler can't just reject it with an error.

#### Alternative Solution

You've mentioned in the comments that in practice, there is no `_HAS_THE_FUNC`, so you cannot define a replacement.
However, if you can't define a replacement, you can simply define an overload:

```cpp
struct incomplete;

template<int _N = 1, typename _F> // we can't just write enable_if_t<false>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<_F, incomplete>> lib_fun(_F f);
```

*See [live solution at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/Y9o8d7PWP).*

If `incomplete` was defined at some point, then hypothetically, `_F` could be the same as `incomplete`.
This is why the compiler can't just reject this.
However, we never define `incomplete` in practice, and thus `lib_fun` is a function for which SFINAE always fails.

#### Further Notes

All names starting with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for the implementation. You should avoid names like `_HAS_THE_FUNC`.

As a side note, `namespace ext { namespace lib`
can be simplified to `namespace ext::lib` since C++17.

Comment: While your proposed solution works, it is not applicable in the given scenario.
The #ifdef _HAS_THE_FUNC does not exist in the external library. Consequently, I can't delete it by using the preprocessor. The function just exists or not (depending on the library version).

Comment: @Hymir would the alternative solution of adding an overload that can never be called work?

Comment: The alternative solution seems to work. Do I understand this correctly, that through the `struct incomplete` we ensure, that the function is always declared?

Comment: @Hymir the function is always declared and the syntax `lib_fun<_N>` is always valid, but substitution would always fail because `_F` is never the same as `incomplete`. `incomplete` is just an arbitrary incomplete type which is never equal to `_F` and which prevents the compiler from diagnosing that `lib_fun` can't actually be called.